# Compiler backend generated from declarative description of the architecture

Tags: compilers

Is it possible, given a declarative description of an architecture's register layout and instruction semantics and machine code encodings, to autogenerate a compiler back-end?

If so, has anyone ever done this?

Comment: LLVM might come close to what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

[João Dias; Norman Ramsey: "Automatically Generating Back Ends Using Declarative Machine Descriptions", *Proc. ACM Symp. Principles of Prog. Lang.*, (POPL-37):403-416, 2010](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/pubs/gentileset.pdf).

I think this goes a bit farther than you asked for, because they're actually looking for *good* code sequences.  For something a little more basic you could go back to some of Norm Ramsey's earlier work, like: [Norman Ramsey; Mary F. Fernández: "Specifying Representations of Machine Instructions", *ACM T. Prog. Lang. and Sys.*, 19(3):492–524, May 1997](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/pubs/specifying.pdf).

There's a long line of research on trying to automatically generate back ends from simpler descriptions.  Look for papers by Christopher W Fraser, David R Hanson and Todd A Proebsting.

Comment: gcc uses [machine description files](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Machine-Desc.html), but it looks like these typically contain additional information to support optimization.